# Surrounded and reversed

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

### The task

In this challenge, your task is to determine whether some string occurs as a substring of a given string both surrounded by another string and reversed.

Your input is a non-empty string **S** of lowercase ASCII letters.
If there exist non-empty strings **A** and **B** such that the concatenation **ABA** and the reversal **rev(B)** are both contiguous substrings of **S**, then your output shall be a truthy value.
Otherwise, your output shall be a falsy value.
The two substrings may occur in any order, and they can even overlap.
However, it can be shown that in all truthy cases, you can either find non-overlapping substrings or a solution where **B** is a palindrome.

### Example

Consider the input string `S = zyxuxyzxuyx`.
We choose `A = xu` and `B = xyz`, and then we can find the following substrings:

```
S      = zyxuxyzxuyx
ABA    =   xuxyzxu
rev(B) = zyx
```

The choice `A = x` and `B = u` would also be valid.
The correct output in this case is truthy.

### Rules and scoring

You can write a full program or a function.
Standard loopholes are disallowed.
The lowest byte count wins.

### Test cases

Truthy

```
sds
aaxyxaa
aaxyaaayx
hgygjgyygj
zyxuxyzxuyx
cgagciicgxcciac
iecgiieagcigaci
oilonnsilasionloiaammialn
abbccdeeaabccddbaacdbbaccdbaaeeccddb
```

Falsy

```
a
aaxyaa
jjygjhhyghj
abcaabbccaabca
egaacxiagxcaigx
lnsiiosilnmosaioollnoailm
cabbccabdcaddccabbddcaabbdcaddccaadcabbccaabbcadcc
```

#### Fun fact

One can construct arbitrarily long falsy strings using four distinct letters, but not using three letters.
The fourth falsy test case is the longest possible.

Comment: I think `abcaabbccaabcaa` is still falsy with three distinct letters.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Choose `A = caa` and `B = b`, and look at the end of the string.

Comment: Oh...yeah I don't have much time to check while golfing...

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
s↔B&sA,B,A~s?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NbcJAEIV78SEnn9JABGWAcngerNmxxjsSK6RdonDwgQqogArogy7cyGY2Qlye3o/0vuEICkWNP@vPen2sy/L7vNe0Xm/bj7Tpt/3mkr5q3XfpkLq@A3LJwMsBKNl94MITFxcP55JPuZzz6X8iBpMIcSYSkDcyEouMrWaQeGOiFmMSRRKLagLMs0Bjw7xRbqbJESEUDg2EgYBhoKbU5pEBygJnQbjR1V/F/DnOliBmqtEgOnffdfcH)

### How it works

```
s↔B&sA,B,A~s?
s              the input has substring temp
 ↔B            temp reversed is B
   &           and the input
    sA         has substring A
      ,B,A     A,B,A
          ~s?  is a substring of input
```

Comment: Ah right. I was wondering how you ensured that A was nonempty, but the `s` immediately after the `&` takes care of that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 40 bytes

```
(.+)(.)+\1.*(?<=(?=(?<-2>\2)+(?(2)A)).*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5BasQwDLz7HwV7QwPNedvQUz@xh45loyg4NtRdsPfzqRK2IGZGw6DRT/yVjP3Ffn3vdhycHd1wexsvdr6@21nn@jp93CY32NlO7tO58eL2vYZqgNYbcDKA3szCnVfuCubR2731R7urTQwmEeJGJCAjkVgkHiaDxBRJJecqCVVKTkWAbROkbOA9UYgRODh4gIL3UK0yxtMz/x@YddXmZem8rCayZptAOyHcTNL7UrQjb6VCSkkpF0jaDJ0l8IEQwiG8Eg56GgjPyIG60B8)

Big thanks to Martin for fixing a bug with the expression.

Matches **ABA** then the rest of the string. While doing this, it pushes **B**'s characters onto a stack. Looks backwards over the whole string to find **B** in reverse order, by traversing forward again and popping characters off of the stack as it matches them (`(?<-2>\2)+`). Then it makes sure the stack is empty by trying to match a capital letter, which won't be in the input, if the stack still is full.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 53 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.scan(/(?=(.+)(.+)\1)/).any?{|a,b|s[b.reverse]}}
```

Fairly straightforward. The only real trick is the positive lookahead `(?=...)` in the regex, which is used to find all matches and not just non-overlapping ones.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5RbsIwEET/fYr8AWob1ANQDkL5GK8XZyPHrmJS2RDOnm6osLSe0ZNmZ8fJ1uXSHJaPr3zPbSbE7X57PGzbt90635@7/a5FrMf7jHc755NtR/7lMfP58Vg22WUDlFqApwKoxXS@@t5X/cytlqnUW5kUk4cnEfKFSEBGmLwIr9CDxCQJKcYsAVlSDEmAYRCEaGAtkWMGVnUWIGct1KtlfjLzusD0vTZ3XfVdr0nCM71GYdhrtAj0BIgvJmidJK2MQ8qQlEKICRIGQ/8p6wjOrcaqrKteAI5ei3Wzkk0bJHJuGdQ1LjXzlfN1No2@n@mam8tpBWfD0S1/)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 95 bytes

```php
<?=($p=preg_match_all)('#(?=(.+)(.+)\1)#',$argn,$t)&&$p(strrev("#".join("|",$t[2])."#"),$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFBbsIwELz7GQZBrCKk9kopDykVmqxdeyPHjhKoHNq@nW6CuPdg72jWszNad6G7vR660Kklep/2GnVNZJ0DpmprgGxdQ7BA52ZO79Rn7h0oVK50MVtX6WPSGz3YQQFlLMBcAYxFBT/6xo9yqetYLmW8lovQ5OGJmXwhYpBiR57ZTaQHscocc0oDRwycU8wMtC0jJvWfjOqRQDWNOIcw@tCIkjCrJymU8yItDIkA9kVFseMslqnNAzjnGFMGx1bRXVVbgrUTqKVMox4ELD0Gy2RhtMEw79R8q8ObLHlfLbt91zt/anGmcEKMplovKmlsn8x0js9msd7Mos3ybFarZVcN5753X5Ve6G2TOVX6R0vv/eXDbIUz99dmd3MU8vQJu9/bHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
Ḣ⁼Ṫȧ
ẆŒṖ€ẎÇÐfẎ€QUẇ€⁸Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkWPGvc83LnqxHKuh7vajk56uHPao6Y1D3f1HW4/PCENSAN5gaEPd7UD6UeNOx7ubPj//39yemJ6cmZmcnpFcnJmYjIA)

Very inefficient.